# accent above a greek letter

Tags: accents

I want to make the greek letter omega with an accent above it.

I know that I make the letter in math mode:

```
$\omega$
```

and I know that I add a accent this way:

```
\'{e}
```

But when I combine the two:

```
\'{$\omega$}
```

I just get the accent before that omega, not above it.

Can anyone advise please?

Comment: Is this a math mode application, or are you trying to write polytonic Greek letters -- in text mode, presumably?

Comment: It wasn't in math mode. But I thought that I had to be in math mode to create the \omega. The \acute{} method worked for me.

Comment: There's a big difference, typographically speaking, between the polytonic (accented) "ώ" character and the output of `$\acute{\omega}$`.

Comment: @Mico Do you know how we can type the polytonic epsilon in text mode in LaTeX/beamer? I'm trying to do this outside of math mode.

Comment: @Ernesto - The best solution, I believe, would be to employ a text font that features the set of polytonic Greek characters. Which font family do you employ at present?

Comment: @Mico - I'm using Times New Roman with the package ``newtxtext``

Comment: @Ernesto - I would think carefully before using a serif font, such as a Times Roman clone, for a `beamer` document. If at all possible, do use a sans-serif OpenType text font, such as `Calibri` or `Noto Sans`, which features a full set of polytonic Greek characters. Then, use either LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, which allow you to employ OpenType font families directly, to compile the document.

Comment: @Mico - Will do that! Thanks

Answer (score 13):

Use `\acute{}` in mathmode:

```
$\acute{\omega}$
```

Other accents in mathmode:

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

\begin{document}

\section*{Accents in mathmode}
    $\begin{array}{llll}
        \underline{\omega} & \verb|\underline{\omega}| &
        \overline{\omega} & \verb|\overline{\omega}| \\
        \hat{\omega} & \verb|\hat{\omega}| &
        \check{\omega} & \verb|\check{\omega}| \\
        \tilde{\omega} & \verb|\tilde{\omega}| &
        \acute{\omega} & \verb|\acute{\omega}| \\
        \grave{\omega} & \verb|\grave{\omega}| &
        \dot{\omega} & \verb|\dot{\omega}| \\
        \ddot{\omega} & \verb|\ddot{\omega}| &
        \breve{\omega} & \verb|\breve{\omega}| \\
        \bar{\omega} & \verb|\bar{\omega}| &
        \vec{\omega} & \verb|\vec{\omega}| \\
    \end{array}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem, but I cannot use the omega in math mode because it is not the correct font. Is there a solution outside mathmode?